# How to pool the interquartile range for an arbitrary distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, pooling

Let's say that I want to estimate the temperature in an annulus-like region. I split the annulus into four equal sectors (sectors 1,2,3, and 4) with $n_i$ being the number of measurements in sector $i$. Let's denote the true temperature in each sector as $t_1$,...,$t_4$. I looked at the distribution of the measurements in each sector.

[image]

The panels on the left are the histograms of measurements from each sector and the panels on the right are the histograms of the log of the measurements. The three red vertical lines are the median and the interquartile range. I don't know if this is a named distribution but the closest thing I see is the log-normal distribution. I did run normality tests on log of the measurements and they all failed fantastically so none of the distributions are actually log-normal.

From each sector I picked the median as a measure of central tendency and compute the overall temperature for the entire ring as the weighted average

$$\hat{t} = \frac{n_1\hat{t_1}+n_2\hat{t_2}+n_3\hat{t_3}+n_4\hat{t_4}}{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4}.$$

Now I also want to report some sort of an interval-estimate/measure-of-spread with $\hat{t}$. The range for all of the sectors is a few orders of magnitudes. The panels on the right show that log(data) ranges from about -4 to 2. For each individual sector, I think the IQR would be a good quantity to report along with $\hat{t_i}$ to show the spread of the data. But my question is, how can I compute an IQR-or-something-analogous for $\hat{t}$. How can I pool these IQR and obtain an interval estimate for $\hat{t}$?

I have to assume that the true underlying distribution form for all four sectors is the same but the parameters (location and spread) are different in each sector. The true parameters are not identical in all of the sectors. Some sectors are supposed to be hotter than others.

---

**Addendum:** As I understand smoothed bootstrapping, for my case, I can pick $n_1$ of the measurements (with replacement) from my sector 1 measurements and add some Gaussian random noise with mean zero.

Question 1: What should be the variance of the gaussian random noise I add? I see $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{n_1}$ from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29#Smoothed_bootstrap) but is there a reference/reason why this over something else? Is this optimal in some sense?

I do this for the rest of the three sectors and then I compute an estimate of my statistic ($\hat{t^*}$) by taking the median of the bootstrap sample from each of the four sectors and then computing the weighted average of the medians.

Question 2: How many times should I repeat this procedure to get a "good" idea of the distribution of my statistic? Just whenever I decide to stop and let my machine rest?

After I have a good number of $\hat{t^*}$, I plot and look at the histogram of all of the $\hat{t^*}$.

Question 3: Just out of curiosity, can we say anything about this distribution in a general case? Is it guaranteed to be symmetric or normal? Or can it take any arbitrary shape?

Let's say the distribution is symmetric-like and I say "Woah, let me take the mean($\hat{t^*}$) and I can even compute and report the 95% CI (for example)".

Question 4: What happens if mean($\hat{t^*}$) and my original $\hat{t}$ are different? I have a bias now. Can I simply subtract the bias from all of my $\hat{t^*}$ estimates so that mean($\hat{t^*}$- bias) = $\hat{t}$ and then compute and report the shifted CI (centered on my $\hat{t})$? Same strategy if I want to report the IQR in which case I compare median($\hat{t^*}$) with my original $\hat{t}$?

Comment: You can't compute interquartile ranges for weighted averages of random variables with arbitary distributions, even if you know the IQRs of the components.

Comment: When you say "they failed fantastically" I presume you mean that the p-values were very low. Nevertheless the distributions may be quite close to normal (perhaps usefully so) -- it looks like your sample sizes are quite large.

Comment: @Glen_b You are right on both accounts. They failed fantastically because $p$ was something like $10^{-3}$ and the sample sizes are on the order of tens of thousands. So are you saying that I can assume log-normal distribution? It is very close. Visually I can't tell the difference. So, even if I assume log-normal distribution, is it possible for me to do a reasonable interval estimate?

Comment: No real data will be perfectly normal/lognormal/..., and with enough observations you can detect even trivial deviations from it. A goodness of fit test doesn't answer the question you need answered ("Is a lognormal model reasonable for my purposes?"), but gives a noisy answer to one you already know the answer to ("Is it lognormal? Nope"). By working with a normal on the log scale, you may be able to get a reasonable estimate of the IQR of the mixture. But that is dependent on the suitability of the model. One possibility is to use something like a smoothed bootstrap to estimate it.

Comment: @Glen_b Wow, I didn't know about this technique at all and it seems very useful. I have read up on it and tried to understand as much as I could but I still have a few questions I couldn't get a clear answer to. Can you please look at the addendum to my question above and let me know what you think? Thanks.